# Stripe checkout - Remove or make email field read only

Tags: javascript, email, stripe-payments, checkout, readonly

I'm using stripe checkout as described in https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

On the server side, I create a new stripe customer (if there isn't one already), and use that customer id to create a checkout session. and then redirect to checkout using stripe api

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
  // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
  // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
  sessionId: '{{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}'
}).then(function (result) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `result.error.message`.
});
```

in the checkout page (which is stripe hosted), there is a email field which is pre populated, but is editable. I have had customers changing that email address. Is there a way I can make the email address on stripe checkout readonly field?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's currently not possible. Providing the customer id allows Stripe to keep Customer and PaymentMethods as up to date as possible. This includes allowing the Customer to change their email address. While not perfect, you could detect those changes in your code using webhooks, and have the user reconcile or verify what should be on the customer object. https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-email

Comment: @v3nkman Do you know if Stripe validates the new email before allowing the payment to go through? I went through the trouble of implementing my own validation before passing the email to the Stripe checkout form, and if Stripe allows them to change the email without validation, this would undermine all that work. At the same time I don't want to just pass `customer_email` per MatiasG's solution, because that can create duplicate customers. I am trying to follow best practices and it's almost like Stripe's API isn't allowing me to do so.

Comment: @cazort This is now resolved by stripe. See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an email from stripe today

> We are disabling customers’ ability to overwrite their email address
> Starting October 26, customers can no longer edit their email address
> after you pass it into a Checkout Session. We’ve made this change to
> prevent duplicative subscriptions from being created by accident for
> existing customers and prevent unexpected updates to the Customer
> object during Checkout.

And here it is in all its glory

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible **work around**:

You can use **customer_email** instead **customer** parameter when you create a session.
In this case users can not change the value of email field.

Then, you can get the created customer and update it if you need added some data using the API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update

But, the problem is that stripe will create a new customer for each checkout.

Comment: Yes, creating duplicate customers is a problem that I want to avoid. I am frustrated with Stripe because best practice is to validate the email *before* accepting payment; if you don't do this, then it is possible to have the payment go through but not have any valid email on file for the customer, and thus you could end up with no way to contact the customer which could create all sorts of problems. So I do this validation on my end before sending it to checkout. It's like Stripe is designed in a way that prevents me from following best practices.

Comment: This "workaround" is especially frustrating given that there is no way using the Stripe API to merge duplicate customers. So I'm forever stuck with the cluttered duplicate information, which makes customer management difficult. It's almost like the people running Stripe have no clue how to actually run databases and generate a functional API. And this is a product that has been around for many years and experienced extensive revision. The fact that these serious flaws and limitations haven't been worked out is mind-boggling. And the saddest part? It's not like any competitor does it better.

Answer (score 0):

Now, according to the [Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer):

> If the customer changes their email on the Checkout page, the Customer object will be updated with the new email.

Comment: A question that I have been unable to find answered in their documentation is *what happens* when the customer changes the email. Does Stripe send a validation email? Does it allow the payment to go through before validating the email? What I'm trying to avoid here is the scenario where the payment goes through but the entered email is invalid. In my testing, Stripe allows this to happen if I just leave the field blank and let the customer specify it on the checkout form. This is unacceptable, so I validated the email myself. But now they allow it to be changed again? It's so frustrating.

Comment: I heard back from Stripe support and they said verbatim: "I’m sorry to say that Stripe Checkout has no functionality of checking email validity beforehand. In this case Since Checkout doesn't support this feature, it is out of our hands to provide you the respective support for it." and their only suggestion was to ditch the checkout page and go with Stripe Elements to get more manual control. My question to them is, why do they even offer a checkout form if it allows scenarios like this? I thought a prebuilt form was so that the coder has less room to screw up, not to prevent best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Stripe allows "customers" to change the email id. we pass to the Checkout form, an idea that could work for you is to add your "internal" identifier (be it an email or other internal user id) as Metatadata to the customer you create, like so (below code is in c#, but you get the idea):

```
Dictionary<string, string> customerMetaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
customerMetaData.Add("myappuserid", "{useyourinternalidhere}");

var customer = await cs.CreateAsync(new CustomerCreateOptions { Email = "{emailthat youwanttouseforcustomer}", Metadata = customerMetaData });

//Now you can pass this customer when you create the session for checkout
```

The point being whatever email the user ends up using, you can always get the corresponding internal user id as well from the customer object's metadata.

In the "success" call back, you can then retrieve the customer data and then save the returned customer details - including the stripe customer id / email that end user used in check out form / your own internal id that you can now retrieve from the customer metadata -- that way you can maintain a mapping of stripe's details to your own internal customer details.

```
//This code is on the "success" call back (when the session id. is passed)
var sessionService = new SessionService();
var session = await sessionService.GetAsync(session_id, new SessionGetOptions { Expand = new List<string> { "customer" , "line_items", "subscription" } });
var sessionCustomer = session.Customer;

//This sessionCustomer now has the metadata that you passed while creating the customer
//Save the Stripe ids / email id along with data retrieved from the Metadata;
//Now you have all the info you required..
```

Of course this response is delayed - hopefully, it helps others...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**"customer_email" parameter**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python#create_checkout_session-customer_email) as shown below and this is the example in **Python**:

```py
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    customer_email='example@gmail.com', # Here
    line_items=[
        {
            'price_data': {
                'currency': 'jpy',
                'unit_amount': 1000,
                'product_data': {
                    'name': 'Honey',
                    'description': 'Good honey',
                },
            },
            'quantity': 1,
        },
    ],
    mode='payment',
    success_url= "https://example.com/success.html",
    cancel_url='https://example.com/cancel',
)
```

And because you use [**"customer_email" parameter**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python#create_checkout_session-customer_email) so **the email field is readonly** as shown below:

[image]